# RegExp in JavaScript, when a quantifier is part of the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to use a regexp that matches any text that is between a caret, less than and a greater than, caret.

So it would look like:  ^< THE TEXT I WANT SELECTED >^

I have tried something like this, but it isn't working: ^<(.*?)>^

I'm assuming this is possible, right? I think the reason I have been having such a tough time is because the caret serves as a quantifier. Thanks for any help I get!

**Update**

Just so everyone knows, they following from am not i am worked

```
 /\^<(.*?)>\^/
```

But, it turned out that I was getting html entities since I was getting my string by using the .innerHTML property. In other words,

```
> ... &gt;
< ... &lt;
```

To solve this, my regexp actually looks like this:

```
\^&lt;(.*?)((.|\n)*)&gt;\^
```

This includes the fact that the string in between should be any character or new line. Thanks!

Comment: [Caret not carrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) :)

Comment: Thank you! I knew that couldn't be right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `^` symbol since it has special meaning in a JavaScript regex.

```
 /\^<(.*?)>\^/
```

In a JavaScript regex, the `^` means *beginning of the string*, unless the `m` modifier was used, in which case it means *beginning of the line*.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
\^<(.*?)>\^
```

In a regex, if you want to use a character that has a special meaning (caret, brackets, pipe, ...), you have to escape it using a backslash. For example, `(\w\b)*\w\.` will select a sequence of words terminated by a dot.

#### Careful!

If you have to pass the regex pattern as a string, i.e. there's no regex literal like in javascript or perl, you may have to use a **double** backslash, which the programming language will escape to a single one, which will then be processed by the regex engine.
Same regex in multiple languages:

```
Python:
  import re
  myRegex=re.compile(r"\^<(.*?)>\^") # The r before the string prevents backslash escaping
PHP:
  $result=preg_match("/\\^<(.*?)>\\^/",$subject); // Notice the double backslashes here?
JavaScript:
  var myRegex=/\^<(.*?)>\^/,
      subject="^<blah example>^";
  subject.match(myRegex);
```

If you tell us what programming language you're writing in, we'll be able to give you some finished code to work with.

Edit: Whoops, didn't even notice this was tagged as javascript. Then, you don't have to worry about double backslash at all.

Edit 2: `\b` represent a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Though I agree yours is what I would have used myself.

Comment: *A sequence of words terminated by a dot?*  I think you meant `(\w+\s+)*\w+\.`